# AngularJs Select with ng-options is passing validation with an empty string

Tags: angularjs, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a select list which is passing my form validation when the default option is selected.

```
<select class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="c.DefectId"
            ng-options="defect.Value as defect.Text for defect in c.DefectList"
            ng-disabled="c.Status"
            ng-required="!c.Status"
            id="DefectId-{{ $index }}" 
            name="DefectId-{{ $index }}">
        <option value="" selected>--Select Defect--</option>
    </select>
```

When

```
<option value="" selected>--Select Defect--</option>
```

is selected my validation passes. myForm.$valid returns true but I want it to  be false.

**EDIT**
c.Status is a boolean value. I want the select to be required when c.Status is false

I have created a plunker with a shortened version of my code and it works in 
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWwQxK8h9OH3Tx2kilWS?p=preview)

I can't figure out why it isn't working.

I'm using Angular with
.Net MVC 5 and Bootstrap running on IIS

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by in my Model DefectId was an int. When this was converted to a JSON object 0 was automatically assigned to it. So when AngularJs parsed the JSON it saw that DefectId was not null so it passed the validation.

To fix this I changed DefectId to int? (nullable int) so when it was converted to JSON it was null and didn't automatically pass validation.

It would have also been possibele to use AngularJs to check that DefectId was greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-required = "true" in your select field then myForm.$valid returns false ,
if ng-required = "false" in your select field then myForm.$valid returns true , check the c.status in your code

like this

```
<select class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="c.DefectId"
            ng-options="defect.Value as defect.Text for defect in c.DefectList"
            ng-disabled="c.Status"
            ng-required="true"
            id="DefectId-{{ $index }}" 
            name="DefectId-{{ $index }}">
        <option value="" selected>--Select Defect--</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I only need the select required when status is false.

Comment: ok fine then your code is write , it will work ..i checked ,   check the status field value

Comment: this is stumping me I have created a plunkr and the same code works there